# ACLs on groups of contacts

Tags: acl

(CiviCRM 4.6.20, Drupal 7.50)

I have had zero luck trying to get this functionality to work.  Here is the setup:

- Created a regular (not smart, didn't want to add that level of potential caching complication yet) group of contacts (let's call it Test Group) to which a specific user should have access.
- Created a group for access control, and added that user to the group.
- Created an ACL role and linked it to the group for access control.
- Created an ACL for editing the Test Group of contacts for the ACL role created in the previous step.
- Logged in as the specific user and can only see the user's own contact record, not any others.
- I have the View All Contacts and Edit All Contacts Drupal permissions turned off for this user's Drupal role, and I even tried turning off the view/edit own contacts Drupal permissions, all to no avail.

There must be a step I'm missing but I've reviewed a lot of documentation and I just don't see where I'm going astray.  If anyone has used this successfully, can you please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance,
Lesley

Comment: Are either of your groups child groups of another group? I had that problem - making them independent groups solved the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately these are not child groups - thanks for your response and sorry for the delay in responding on my end.  :-)